# Why does NetInfo not work for Web but works for Android (react-native-web)?

Tags: react-native-web

When using react-native-web NetInfo works fine for Android and iOS but is not working for web.

To confirm the code being run for web is the same as Android I console log in the `componentDidMount` and both Android and Web display the text. However the events dont seem to be working for the web version.

```
// src/App.js

import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './utilities/storage/store';
import EntryScreen from './screens/EntryScreen';
import Routing, { Router } from './utilities/routing/index';
import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';

const Route = Routing.Route;

class App extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('App mounted');
        NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectivityChange);
    }

    /**
     * Listens for any internet connectivity changes.
     * @param isConnected The internet connection status
     */
    handleConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
        console.log ('bam');
        console.log ('Connected:', isConnected);
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router>
                    <Route path="/" component={EntryScreen} />
                </Router>
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

I would expect, based on the documentation that NetInfo works for web as well as Android. If it does not can someone provide a way to do this please.

```
"react": "^16.2.0",
"react-art": "^16.2.0",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-native": "0.57.8",
"react-native-web": "0.9.13",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetInfo on the web is missing some functionality compared to iOS and Android React Native. There is just not equivalent web APIs.

https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/blob/master/README.md#modules

Comment: Yeah I also read some articles that said web consideres a LAN connection a valid connection even if there is not access to the WWW. So using things like the windows event listeners like 'online' / 'offline' are known to return true even if there is no connection to the web.